# Anexo de curriculum via e-mail no Codeigniter não funcionando

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Boa tarde, estou utilizando este código para receber alguns dados de supostos candidatos que se inscrevam no site.

Gostaria que o candidato envie o arquivo em anexo.

As views estão ok.. e acho que o problema está no meu codigo deste controller :

**Recebo todos os dados solicitados no formulário. Tudo ok, porem o anexo não vem.**

```
class Envio extends CI_Controller {

    function trabalheconosco()
    {   
        $this->load->library('email');


        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/curriculum/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|txt|pdf';
  $config['max_size'] = '100000';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $info['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');         
        $info['nomepai'] = $this->input->post('nomepai');       
        $info['nomemae'] = $this->input->post('nomemae');       
        $info['cpf'] = $this->input->post('cpf');           
        $info['rg'] = $this->input->post('rg');         
        $info['orgao'] = $this->input->post('orgao');       
        $info['data'] = $this->input->post('data');         
        $info['telefone'] = $this->input->post('telefone');     
        $info['cel'] = $this->input->post('cel');           
        $info['datanasc'] = $this->input->post('datanasc');     
        $info['naturalidade'] = $this->input->post('naturalidade'); 
        $info['estado'] = $this->input->post('estado');     
        $info['email'] = $this->input->post('email');       
        $info['anexo'] = $this->input->post('anexo');       

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->clear();



  $this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('anexo'));
  $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

  $this->email->attach($upload_data['full_path']);

        $this->email->from($info['email'], $info['nome']);
        $this->email->to('meuemail');
        $this->email->subject('Curriculum enviado por'.$info['nome']);
        $this->email->message
            (
                                        "Nome: " . $info['nome'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Nome do Pai: " . $info['nomepai'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Nome da Mãe: " . $info['nomemae'] . "\n\n" .
                            "CPF: " . $info['cpf'] . "\n\n" .
                            "RG: " . $info['rg'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Orgão Emissor: " . $info['orgao'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Data de expedição: " . $info['data'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Telefone: " . $info['telefone'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Celular: " . $info['cel'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Data de nascimento: " . $info['datanasc'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Naturalidade: " . $info['naturalidade'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Estado: " . $info['estado'] . "\n\n" .
                            "Anexo: " . $info['anexo'] . "\n\n".
                            "Email: " . $info['email'] . "\n" 
            );

             if ($this->email->send()) {
                     echo '     <script> 
                                alert("Obrigado por se candidatar! Seu curriculum será analizado, em breve retornaremos! Boa sorte!");
                                window.location.href = "http://meusite.com.br";
                                </script>'; 
             return true;
         } else {
             show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
         }
}
```

A view:

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="row">
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url("/index.php/envio/trabalheconosco");?>">
                      <fieldset class="form-group" >

                        <label for="nome">Nome completo:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" required>

                      </fieldset>   

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="nomepai">Nome do Pai:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomepai" name="nomepai" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="nomemae">Nome da Mãe:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomemae" name="nomemae" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="cpf" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="rg">RG:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" name="rg" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">                         

                        <label for="orgao">Orgão Emissor:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orgao" name="orgao" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="data">Data de expedição:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="telefone">Telefone Fixo:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="(DDD)XXXX-XXXX" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="cel">Celular:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cel" name="cel" placeholder="(DDD)XXXXX-XXXX" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="datanasc">Data de nascimento:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datanasc" name="datanasc" placeholder="XX/XX/XXXX" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="naturalidade">Naturalidade:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="naturalidade" name="naturalidade" placeholder="Estado/Cidade" required>

                      </fieldset>

                       <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado" placeholder="Ex:SP" required>

                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">               
                        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ex: seuemail@email.com" required>
                      </fieldset>

                      <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label for="anexo">Anexo</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="anexo" name="anexo">
                        <small class="text-muted">Não envie ficheiros e arquivos compactados.</small>
                      </fieldset>

                      <div class="row" align="center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Coloca o form html tbm.

Comment: @rray ok, está incluso agora, verifique por gentileza

Comment: Faltou o entype no form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: inseri e nada ainda.. nao seria algo no meu controller?

Comment: O CI sempre considera q vc esta na raiz do projeto, mude `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/curriculum/` para `$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/curriculum/` e se certifique que na raiz do projeto existem essas pastas.

Comment: Deu certo agora!!! Perfeito Rray !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A abertura do form tem que ser do tipo multipart, dessa forma: `<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

Além disso, no controlador, troque a linha: `$this->upload->do_upload($this->input->post('anexo'));`, por: `$this->upload->do_upload('anexo');`.

O arquivo upado não chega via POST.

Comment: eu já tinha tentado com o mesmo codigo na linha que vc falou.. Substitui por via das duvidas e nao deu certo ainda.. :(

Comment: Já testou separar o load da biblioteca da inicialização da mesma?
Exemplo: `$this->load->library('upload'); $this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: Tenta também ver qual o possível erro que pode estar acontecendo com o upload, dessa forma: `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('anexo')) { echo $this->upload->display_errors(); }`

Comment: Simão, apareceu esta mensagem: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: Essa mensagem diz que o caminho que você setou para upload não é válido.

Comment: O rray deu uma dica que resolveu, mesmo assim obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Faltou por enctype="multipart/form-data" ali no form

Comment: fiz a inserção do enctype, e testei.. nada ainda.. seria algo no meu controller?